# How to check if a property exists in a JSONObject without calling .getJSONObject(key) several times?

Tags: java, json, org.json

I'm processing deeply nested JSON data. Here is a shortened example:

```
{  
   "timestamp":"123",
   "layers":{  
      "frame_raw":"123",
      "frame":{  
         "frame_frame_interface_id":"0",
         "frame_interface_id_frame_interface_name":"asd",
         ...
      },
      "eth_raw":"123",
      "eth":{  
         "eth_eth_dst_raw":"asd",
         "eth_eth_dst":"asd",
         ...
      },
      "ip_raw":"123",
      "ip":{  
         "ip_ip_version_raw":"4",
         "ip_ip_version":"4",

         "ip_ip_addr_raw":[  
            "asd",
            "asd"
         ],
         "ip_ip_addr":[  
            "1.1.1.1",
            "1.1.1.1"
         ],
         "ip_ip_dst_host":"1.1.1.1"
      }
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

I have a list of structures that I explicitly allow. All others should be deleted from the JSON. An example for the list:

```
###frame###
layers.frame_raw
###eth###
layers.eth.eth_eth_dst
layers.eth.eth_eth_src
###ip###
layers.ip.ip_ip_src
layers.ip.ip_ip_dst
layers.ip.ip_ip_src_host
layers.ip.ip_ip_dst_host
layers.ip.ip_ip_version
layers.ip.ip_ip_hdr_len
layers.ip.ip_ip_dsfield
```

My problem is that I can only navigate through the JSON structure using "getJSONObject(key)".

How can I generate the path of the lowest elements of my JSON structure in the form "key.key.key..." so that I can match it with my list?

Comment: `org.json` is simple tool based on the `Map`. If you need things like `JSONPath` use [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) or [`JsonPath`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON object has a method called .has which will return a boolean value. So the logic is like to check whether the JSON object exists. If so check the child node for more existence of your data. If there is an array you have to get the array and migrate through the array using any loop and do the same. For example:

```
   if (json.has("ip")) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = getJSONObject.getString("ip")
        String ip_ip_version_raw = jsonObject.getString("ip_ip_version_raw"));
        if (jsonObject.has("ip_ip_addr_raw")){
            JSONArray ip_ip_addr_raw = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ip_ip_addr_raw");
            for (String s : ip_ip_addr_raw) {
                ...
            }
        } 
    }
```

For reference :

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the existence of a property of a `JSONObject` there is a method called `has`. [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)) is the link to the official documentation.

Comment: I know this method but it doesn't really help me. Basically i need the "path" of all deepest keys. Is there is simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution because the structure in my special case is always `layers.layer.property`, so the depth of the structure is always the same and not variable.

For interested people:

```
for (Iterator<String> layersIterator = jsonObject.getJSONObject("layers").keys(); layersIterator.hasNext(); ) {
    String layer = layersIterator.next();
    for (Iterator<String> propertyIterator = jsonObject.getJSONObject("layers").getJSONObject(layer).keys(); propertyIterator.hasNext(); ) {
        String property = propertyIterator.next();
        System.out.println("layers."+layer+"."+property);
    }
}
```